# WebView Not show when admob banner ads add

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I don't know why my webView is show show when I put admob banner ads

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

[image: problem]

When I remove admob then my webview  show perfectly

#### web.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp">

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:id="@+id/myProcessBar"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:max="100" 
            android:progress="45"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/pb"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        
        
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    
        
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

### Please someone help me :-

### web_main.java

```
package com.musicwala.djaman;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import org.apache.http.conn.util.PublicSuffixList;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Build;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.Manifest;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.style.UpdateAppearance;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.view.View; 
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
public class web_main extends Activity
{
    private AdView mAdView;
    ProgressBar superProgressBar;
    WebView superWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
        // TODO: Implement this method
        setContentView(R.layout.web);
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-1075872442233861~4332615881");
        superProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.myProcessBar);
        superWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        //Set Max Progress Bar
        superProgressBar.setMax(100);
        superWebView.loadUrl("http://musicwala.cf");
        superWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        final SwipeRefreshLayout finalMySwipeRefreshLayout1;
        finalMySwipeRefreshLayout1 = findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
        finalMySwipeRefreshLayout1.setColorSchemeColors(Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN);
        finalMySwipeRefreshLayout1.setOnRefreshListener( new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    // This method performs the actual data-refresh operation.
                    // The method calls setRefreshing(false) when it's finished.
                    
                    superWebView.loadUrl(superWebView.getUrl());
                    
                    //finalMySwipeRefreshLayout1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
        superWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    finalMySwipeRefreshLayout1.setRefreshing(false);
                    //.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
        });
        
        superWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view,int newprogress){
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newprogress);
                superProgressBar.setProgress(newprogress);
                
                    superProgressBar.setProgressTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                    
                    
                
                if(newprogress == 100)
                {
                
                    superProgressBar.setVisibility(view.GONE);
                }
                else
                {
                    superProgressBar.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                }
                
                
            }
            
            
            @Override
            public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view,String title){
                super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);
                getActionBar().setTitle(title);
                getActionBar().setSubtitle("MusicWala");
                getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));
            }
            
        });
        superWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener(){

                @Override
                public void onDownloadStart(String url, String useragent, String contentdisposition, String mimetype, long contentlenth)
                {
                    // TODO: Implement this method
                    alertbox(url,useragent,contentdisposition,mimetype);
                }

                private void alertbox(final String url,final String useragent,final String contentdispositon,final String mimetype)
                {
                    // TODO: Implement this method
                    
                    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(web_main.this);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Download");
                    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Do You Want To Download");
                    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface Dialog,int which){
                            //Download Start
                            
                            //Checking Android Version
                            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                                //Androidb Version 6 or upper
                            {
                                if(checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                                {
                                    //Now Downlaod Start * Permission is granded
                                    downloadStart(url,useragent,contentdispositon,mimetype);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //Permission request
                                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(web_main.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                                    Toast.makeText(web_main.this,"Click On Download Button",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //Android Version 5 or below
                                downloadStart(url,useragent,contentdispositon,mimetype);
                            }
                            
                        }

                        private void downloadStart(String url, String useragent, String contentdispositon, String mimetype)
                        {
                            // TODO: Implement this method
                            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                                Uri.parse(url));
                            final String fileName=URLUtil.guessFileName(url,contentdispositon,mimetype);
                            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/MusicWala",fileName);
                            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                            dm.enqueue(request);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading Started...", //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
                                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface Dialog,int which){

                                //Download Cancel
                                Dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        alertDialogBuilder.create().show();
                }
                

            
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        //super.onBackPressed();
        if(superWebView.canGoBack()){
            superWebView.goBack();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        MenuInflater Inflater = getMenuInflater();
        Inflater.inflate(R.menu.all_menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.download:
                //Settings Item
                Intent download= new Intent(web_main.this,download.class);
                startActivity(download);
                break;
            case R.id.settings:
                //Settings Item
                Intent setting= new Intent(web_main.this,setting.class);
                startActivity(setting);
                break;
                
            case R.id.update:
                //Update Item

                Intent Update = new Intent(web_main.this,update.class);
                startActivity(Update);
                break;
                
            case R.id.about:
                //Settings Item

                Intent about = new Intent(web_main.this,about.class);
                startActivity(about);
                break;
                
            case R.id.exit:
                //Settings Item
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                System.exit(1);
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    

    
    
}
```

Comment: post some code how do you load banner and `WebView` content

Comment: ```MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
  superProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.myProcessBar);
  superWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
  mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
  mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);```

Comment: I think problem in XML file not java

Comment: When I remove admob then work perfect

Comment: basic on this tiny snippet you shown in comment - I don't see a line for loading any content for `WebView`, so thats the reason for empty web content. If you want help you have to post WHOLE code related to the issue. By editing question, not few obvious lines in comment...

Comment: Recheck my question please

Answer (score 0):

your code looks pretty clean and proper, lets try to change first layout from

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

to

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

and see what will happen

also what do you mean by

> When I remove admob

you are not requesting for data (e.g. by commenting out `mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);`) or do you remove whole `<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView` layout from XML?

btw. remove your unique keys and ids, never post them anywhere...

Comment: When I Using Relative Layout Then Ads Showing But My Progress Bar is Not Showing

Comment: have you replaced `RelativeLayout`with `LinearLayout`? does this help for `WebView`?

Comment: btw. you are inflating `setContentView(R.layout.web);` but posted `web_main` layout XML file